# Inserting DateTime on Vb.Net SQL Server CE

Tags: vb.net, datetime, sql-server-ce

I want to insert into a SQL Server CE (`.sdf`) a birth date, read from a `.csv` file.

The `TextLine(5)` is the date in string format: `ddMMyyyy`

I convert it to a VB `DateTime()`, it converts at this way: `Day/Month/Year`

After that, I insert it into SQL Server CE, everything good but the problem is, on the database is always showing as `01/01/1900`, what am I doing wrong?

Also I put a `Console.WriteLine` to check if there is any error, no errors as I expected.

`apadronado.fecnac` is an `DateTime` also my provider is an `cultureinfo` is an `en-US`

I have the following code:

```
apadronado.fecnac = DateTime.ParseExact(TextLine(5).ToString & " 00:00", _
  "yyyyMMdd HH:mm", provider)
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO personas VALUES ('" & apadronado.ci & "','" & _
   apadronado.nombre & "','" & apadronado.apellido & "','" & _
   apadronado.dpto & "','" & apadronado.ciudad & "'," & _
   apadronado.fecnac & ")"
Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText)
Try
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As Exception
  Console.WriteLine(ex)
End Try
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I fixed by using parameters! Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add single quotes around the date value.

Change:

```
apadronado.ciudad & "'," & _
   apadronado.fecnac & ")"
```

to:

```
apadronado.ciudad & "','" & _
   apadronado.fecnac & "')"
```